# Ember js simple auth how to redirect to a different page?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Hey so I have simple auth and I want my index page to be only for users that are logged in and instead of redirecting them to the login page I want them to be redirected to my welcome page. All other pages that they are not authorized to use i want them still sent to the login page. It is only different for my index page. I tried doing an if statement and a redirect in the index.js route but nothing seems to work. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

### Update

so i tried to change the configuration and have it redirect to a welcome page like so.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
import Configuration from 'ember-simple-auth/configuration';
import ENV from 'myApp/config/environment';

ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
  authenticationRoute: 'welcome'
};

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

This however still brings me to the login page.

Comment: Put index.js route file - what you tried  for `I tried doing an if statement and a redirect in the index.js route`

Comment: I have it authenticating in the route for index.js with the AuthenticatedRouteMixin but it brings me to the login page now as my default page every time i go to my webpage. I want it to go to a welcome page instead as the main page of my website.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for this. The best option is to set the `authenticationRoute` in your `config/environments.js` file, as described [here](https://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/Configuration.html#property_authenticationRoute).

The other thing you can do is to define the `beforeModel` hook on your route, and redirect to your welcome page manually if the user is not logged in. Its important to notice that if you chose this path you should not call `this._super()` if you redirect and use the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin`, because the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` will basically redirect to the login route specified in your `config/environments.js` when the `beforeModel` hook is entered.

Comment: Thats what i attempted to do but it was not working (the second option you had mentioned). Maybe I am doing something wrong? Would you mind showing me how I could do this because every time I try i receive an unexpected token error. Sorry I am new to ember js

Comment: Well, I strongly recommend you the first approach, but if you have non-working code maybe show it to us. Or build an non-working `ember-twiddle`. Just edit your question.